# NSPredicate won't work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have a to-many relationship between 2 entities. Athlete(evals)<-->>Eval(whosEval). I am trying to display only the evals of the athlete who was selected. However, when I try to access the relationship through eval.whosEval, I get an undefined error. When I run the app, the table is empty, whereas if I comment out the predicate, it displays ALL Evals for ALL the Athletes. Am I missing something? Thank you.

allEvals.m

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Evaluations",_athletesFullName];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *athleteRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    [athleteRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    NSError *athleteError = nil;
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:athleteRequest error:&athleteError];
    NSPredicate *athletePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"full == %@", _athletesFullName];
    [request setPredicate:athletePredicate];
    Athlete *currentAthlete = [results objectAtIndex:0];

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whosEval == %@", currentAthlete];
   [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSEntityDescription *eval = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Eval" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:eval];



    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor =
    [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date_recorded"
                                ascending:NO
                                 selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }

    [self setEvalArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"Athlete's Full Name is: %@",_athletesFullName);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate uses the athlete name when it should really use the athlete object:

```
@"whosEval == %@", self.athlete
```

Comment: i'm 99.9% thats the error. im currently using a string, but when I set the relationship, I _did_ use the athlete object. When accessing the athlete object in the same method though, can I share the managedObjectContext I used for eval?

Comment: All your objects must be in the same context (so yes).

Comment: updated code, now I get results, but not the correlating evals for each athlete, just all evals altogether.

Comment: Print the evals for the athlete (using the relationship) - what do you get compared to the table contents.

Comment: I didn't set anything for athlete(evals), just evals(whosEval). I thought you only had to set one side? I don't even know how I would set that? How would I select the evals?

Comment: You only need to set one side if the inverse is configured. But this is about debugging and checking what data is actually set. Log the relationship content.

Comment: thanks for your continuous help. So I checked my data model and it does says that evals are the inverse of whosEval, so does that mean I _do_ need to still set it manually? or is that not what you meant by configured?

Comment: That's fine. Log the data at runtime and see what it contains.

Answer (score 1):

You call

```
NSLog(@"This eval is for: %@", eval.whosEval);
```

But you declared `eval` as:

```
NSEntityDescription *eval = ...
```

So there is no way that class `NSEntityDescription` know what "whosEval" is.

Retrieve actual instance of `Eval` object from the `mutableFetchResults` and invoke `whosEval` on it:

```
if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
    //handle error
} else {

    [self setEvalArray:mutableFetchResults];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"Athlete's Full Name is: %@",_athletesFullName);
    NSLog(@"This eval is for: %@", [[mutableFetchResults lastObject] whosEval]);
}
```

Comment: property whosEval isn't found on object of type "id"

Comment: Try that: NSLog(@"This eval is for: %@", [[mutableFetchResults lastObject] whosEval]);  Plus check what Wain wrote, since it looks like you have more problems with your code...